# Can you use Chrome Custom Tabs in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget

In this documentation **https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/** it says you have to add the AndroidX Browser Library in your project.

> Open the app/build.gradle file and add the browser library to the dependencies section"

But I think that's some Android Studio thing.Then I tried to find maybe a NuGet Package but the only thing that showed was some Chrome Custom Tabs version 1.0.0 that couldn't even install:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.ChromeCustomTabs 1.0.0 is not
> compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package
> Xamarin.Android.ChromeCustomTabs 1.0.0 supports: monoandroid50
> (MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0)

Is there any way I can use Chrome's Custom Tabs in my Xamarin Project?

Comment: Try Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser

Answer (score 0):

> Open the app/build.gradle file and add the browser library to the
> dependencies section"

For this problem,you can try to install nuget [Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser/) which is developed by Microsoft. Meanwhile, you also need to install nuget [Xamarin.AndroidX.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core/) .

For more details , you can check: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX.

> Is there any way I can use Chrome's Custom Tabs in my Xamarin Project?

For this , you can try to install nuget [Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs/).